# Hide password protected posts

Tags: password

If I create a post and set the visibility to "password protected", it still shows up on the front page and in the feeds. Is it possible to hide posts from general view altogether, but still allow quick access to some people without creating an account for them?

(This is in WP 3.0.4)

Answer (score 6):

Both the `the_content()` and the `the_excerpt()` template tags already account for password-protected posts, via the [`post_password_required()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_password_required) conditional. If you need to output content, or comments, etc. outside of `the_content()`/`the_excerpt()`, call the `post_password_required()` conditional directly.

For example, if you don't want the comments template to be output if the post is password-protected. you could do the following:

```
if ( ! post_password_required() && ( is_single() || ( is_page() && comments_open() ) ) ) {          
    comments_template( '', true );
}
```

Or, if you don't want to display the post at all if it is password-protected, you could do something like this, inside the Loop:

```
if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
} else {
    // Normal Loop Post output goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My very simple solution is to put something like this in your loop:

```
<?php if( post_password_required() ) continue; ?>
```

This just skip the password protected entry.

Comment: This is going to screw up your pagination.  Eg. if a password protected post is one of your, let's say, 10 on a given page, the page will only contain 9 posts.